# Windows 10 - Py command works Python command fails, Atom script failure

Tags: python, windows-10, atom-editor

I am getting started with Python. I have downloaded the [latest version](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and installed on my Windows 10. I did default instead of Advanced Settings. So I had to update the **PATH** environment variable to include `\Python39` and `\Python39\scripts`. I added **PYTHONPATH** environment variable as well.

It seems to be working fine with `py` command. But with `python` command, I receive an error. I thought I would deal with it. But I went on to try out Atom ([reference vid setups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei-G0fEOu9I&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge)), and script execution returns an error: "Python was not found;".

Does somebody know how to make Python command work? Without reinstallation would be great. The biggest issue is I need the Atom script execution to work.

I looked at other SO posts. I have added the variables but I am unable to execute from within Atom script editor.

`py --version`

> Python 3.9.1

`python --version`

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

`$Env:path`

> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;**C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39**;**C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts**;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\atom\bin

`$Env:pythonpath`

> C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

`dir`

> Directory of C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
>
> 01/12/2021  11:34 AM              .
>
> 01/12/2021  11:34 AM              ..
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM              Python39
>
> 0 File(s)              0 bytes
>
> 3 Dir(s)  838,125,592,576 bytes free

'dir'

Directory of C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39

> 01/12/2021  11:36 AM    < DIR >          .
>
> 01/12/2021  11:36 AM    < DIR >          ..
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          DLLs
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          Doc
>
> 01/12/2021  11:34 AM    < DIR >          include
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          Lib
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          libs
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM            32,622 LICENSE.txt
>
> 12/07/2020  06:13 PM         1,036,976 NEWS.txt
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM           101,432 python.exe
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM            59,448 python3.dll
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM         4,451,896 python39.dll
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM            99,896 pythonw.exe
>
> 01/12/2021  11:36 AM    < DIR >          Scripts
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          tcl
>
> 01/12/2021  11:35 AM    < DIR >          Tools
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM            94,088 vcruntime140.dll
>
> 12/07/2020  06:12 PM            36,744 vcruntime140_1.dll
>
> 8 File(s)      5,913,102 bytes
>
> 10 Dir(s)  838,351,183,872 bytes free

Youtube vid screenshot (advanced install) * *I did standard* *

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvcQlPZ8ecA&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge2

[image]

Atom execution error (Script package installed)

[image]

Comment: So, when you installed it, your install location was `C:\Users\starf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`? What's in that folder? And what happens if you run `python` in a command prompt?

Comment: @RandomDavis - added directory contents to the post

Comment: Dumb question maybe, but did you restart Atom and/or your system after changing your PATH?

Comment: Yes system rebooted after PATH change. I think the issue is specific to Atom execution using 'python' instead of 'py'.

Comment: @RandomDavis - I put the paths in user instead of system variables. Seems that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer about Atom code editor script profile works, but it's not the best answer. My path was added in the **`User variables`** instead of the **`System variables`**. I added PYTHONPATH to system variable with 2 paths. And now the Atom code editor works great with standard profile.

I am new to Python. But the Atom editor is pretty simple to setup and use. And so far I like how you get a clean output of the results simply by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is specific to Atom code editor. Solution is as follows. This article helped ([link](https://discuss.atom.io/t/problem-with-script-does-not-recognize-python/51521/6)).

- script is configured to use the python command to execute all Python files. You can override this by setting up a config profile, which will allow you to tell script to use the correct command (py).
- Navigate the menus down to Packages -> Script and you will see an option to Configure Script. After that, you want to use Run with profile.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]